# Wordpress admin page plugin settings

Tags: php, wordpress, function, plugins, admin

I'm trying to make my first plugin admin page, but I'm getting error:

My plugin folder hierarchy:

```
  uploadsdir-manager 
    index.html
    test.php
    functions.php
    admin-page.php
```

in functions I've added this  code:

```
function awesome_page_create() {
$page_title = 'My Awesome Admin Page';
    $menu_title = 'Awesome Admin Page';
    $capability = 'edit_posts';
    $menu_slug = 'awesome_page';
    $function = 'my_awesome_page_display';
    $icon_url = '';
    $position = 99;

    add_menu_page( $page_title, $menu_title, $capability, $menu_slug, 
$function, $icon_url, $position );
}
add_action('admin_menu', 'awesome_page_create');
```

and then I'm getting this error:

```
  Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function add_action() 
  in
  C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\uploadsdir-
  manager\functions.php:2 
  Stack trace: 
  #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\uploadsdir-
  manager\index.html(11): 
  include() #1 {main} 
  thrown in 
  C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-
  content\plugins\uploadsdirmanager\functions.php 
  on line 2
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

When creating a plugin there is no need for a function page unless your going to import that functions.php.
Worpress reads the file that has the same name as the directory. In example my plugin directory is called emailblast. The true functions page to wordpress is emailblast.php

emailblast.php would start its code like so...

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Email Blasts
 * Plugin URI:  https://yoursite.com
 * Description: These are various email templates that can be sent to an given email using as click of a button.
 * Version:     1.0
 * Author:      your name

 */
```

Comment: fixed this problem with: require(realpath (dirname(__FILE__) . '\..\..\..') . '/wp-load.php');

Comment: That works but to avoid having to require you could just do what I said to avoid the loading of that large require. That could work adversely later. My way is the wordPress recommended way.